# is it possible to spell check PDF files?

Tags: pdf, spellcheck, latex

Is it possible to spell check PDF files? In Preview.app the "Edit > Spelling & Grammar > Check Document Now (⌘;)" is disabled. I'm working on a LaTeX document in Emacs and would like to use the OS X spell checker. A solution for accessing the built in spellchecking dictionary from Emacs would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would install aspell with a package manager like brew and then run that on the .tex file. Unless I'm mistaken emacs has support for aspell built-in.

You can also turn on spell checking in your terminal (iterm2) or emacs GUI.

Comment: That's a good list of options you are mentioning. Can you please add some details on how to install aspell and/or turn on spell checking in Terminal?

Comment: This did not completely answer my question since it uses a custom dictionary file and not the OS X dictionary. But it is possible that this is still the best solution so I'll accept it for now :)

Comment: @patrix I am on OS X and installed aspell with homebrew `brew install aspell --lang=en`. I then added this to my .emacs


`(setq ispell-program-name "/usr/local/bin/aspell")
    (setenv "ASPELL_CONF" nil)
    (autoload 'flyspell-babel-setup "flyspell-babel")
    (add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'flyspell-babel-setup)`


Spell check an entire buffer with M-x flyspell-buffer and check a word for spellings with M-x ispell-word, choose an alternative from the numbers or add to your dictionary with `i`. I'm using Carbon Emacs. Other dists my need you to install emacs' aspell manually.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19026248/240004 has good instructions on how to install emacs, aspell, and homebrew in a manner I prefer.